# React Native not go to button play

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, android-tv

I have a problem when I press the btn of the remote control on the right side to go to the details of the movies, this button is not marked, but when I remove the text it does go directly to the play button.

Sorry for my basic english!!

[With Text IMAGEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWplw.png)

[without Text IMAGEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lHWZ.png)

```
This is my code

    <View style={style.container}>
            {dataFake.map((item, index) => {
                return <View style={{ marginTop: 20, marginLeft: 20, width: 120, position: 'relative' }} key={index}>
                    <View onPress={() => console.log(1)}>
                        <Text>
                            Some text
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                    <View pointerEvents="none">
                        <ImageBackground source={{ uri: item.image }}
                            resizeMode={'contain'} style={{
                                borderTopLeftRadius: 10,
                                borderTopRightRadius: 10,
                                borderBottomEndRadius: 10,
                                borderBottomStartRadius: 10,
                                overflow: 'hidden',
                            }}>
                            <View style={{ width: '100%', backgroundColor: 'black', height: 180, opacity: 0.5 }}></View>

                        </ImageBackground>
                    </View>
                    <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => console.log(item.id)} underlayColor={'#00B9AE'} style={{ width: '100%', color: 'white', marginTop: 10 }} >
                        <View style={style.btnView}>
                            <Text style={style.playBtn}>Play</Text>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                </View>
            })}
        </View >
```